# Telnet connection getting closed if I keep fifo open from script

Tags: python, scripting, telnet, fifo

I have a python script which is sending commands to a fifo file through this command.

```
printf "command" > my1.fifo
```

An another process (telnet login) is taking input from this my1.fifo file. The python script analyses the output of telnet connection and then sends the commands to my1.fifo file.

The script is like this

```
python3.10 strrr.py &
cat >my1.fifo &
cat my1.fifo | telnet 172.27.172.247 10031 > log.txt 2>&1 &
```

When I run these commands individually everything is working fine but when I run all these through a script either the connection to telnet gets closed or fifo file doesn't send the command to telnet process.

Comment: Check for errors in the log file generated by telnet. or Try adding some delay in the script between the commands to ensure that each command has enough time to complete before the next one starts.

Comment: It is running well if i run commands manually.